# Creación de tabla en sql Oracle con condición

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

¿Como creo una tabla con una restriccion? Por ejemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEES(
ID NUMBER(5, 0) NOT NULL,
MANAGER_ID NUMBER(5, 0),
DATE_OF_JOINING DATE NOT NULL,
NAME VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL,
LAST_NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
SALARY NUMBER
);
```

Donde el campo SALARY  debe aceptar numero mayor a 50000. En un select si lo se hacer pero al momento de crear la tabla no.

Agradeceria si me indicaran como.

Answer (score 1):

```html
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEES(
ID NUMBER(5, 0) NOT NULL,
MANAGER_ID NUMBER(5, 0),
DATE_OF_JOINING DATE NOT NULL,
NAME VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL,
LAST_NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
SALARY NUMBER,
CONSTRAINT min_salary CHECK (salary > 50000));
```

[**FUENTE**](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/check.php)

Comment: Gracias @antonio291093,  ya me funciono